# C read values from text file

Tags: c

I'm writing a c program to simulate FCFS scheduling algorithm. It will accept a command line argument as a file and calculate turnaround time and wait time for every process. However it can not read values from text file into variables successfully.
Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 50

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    char line[20];
    int n=0;
    typedef struct
    {
            char name; //process name
            int at;  //arrive time
            int pt;  //process time
            int ft;  //finish time
            int rt;  //round time
            int wt;  //wait time
    } Process;
    Process pcs[N];

    FILE* file = fopen( argv[1], "r");
    while (fgets(line,sizeof(line),file) != NULL)
    {
            sscanf(line, "%s %d %d", pcs[i].name, pcs[i].at, pcs[i].pt);
            line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
            printf("%s %d %d\n",pcs[i].name, pcs[i].at, pcs[i].pt);
            i++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    pcs[0].ft=pcs[0].at+pcs[0].pt;
    pcs[0].rt=pcs[0].ft-pcs[0].at;
    pcs[0].wt=0;
    for (n;n<4;n++)
    {
            if (pcs[n].at<pcs[n-1].ft)
            {
                    pcs[n].ft=pcs[n-1].ft+pcs[n].pt;
                    pcs[n].rt=pcs[n].ft-pcs[n].at;
                    pcs[n].wt=pcs[n-1].ft-pcs[n].at;
            }
            else
            {
                    pcs[n].ft=pcs[n].at+pcs[n].pt;
                    pcs[n].rt=pcs[n].ft-pcs[n].at;
                    pcs[n].wt=pcs[n-1].ft-pcs[n].at;
            }
    }
            int x = 0;
    for (x;x<n;x++)
    {
            printf("process name: %s", pcs[x].name);
            printf("Turnaround Time: %d", pcs[x].rt);
            printf("Wait Time: %d\n", pcs[x].wt);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Here is the input file

[image: input]

And the output is

[image: output]

Thanks for any help and advice.

Comment: a.) `char name` stores ***exactly one*** character, that's it. b.) Take the compiler's warnings serious.

Comment: compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then  **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by alk, you're doing some mistakes:

1. In your struct declaration you have declared `name` as a single character, but in your file reading code(while loop containing `fgets`) you're passing `%s` which is for strings, so better change your declaration to a `char name[SIZE]` rather than `char name`. Bdw you should read the compiler warning and try to understand it, since that's what is creating problem.
2. You are supposed to pass address of variables in `sscanf` and it's variants, so change line 26 to:
   `sscanf(line, "%s %d %d", pcs[i].name, &pcs[i].at, &pcs[i].pt);`